# Reducing a System of Polynomial Equations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, mathematical-software, polynomials

I am currently writing a program in SAGE which computes Nilpotent Orbit Varieties for an Algebraic Geometry research project and I have reduced my problem to the following:

> Consider a system of polynomial equations $\{f_{1},...,f_{n}\}$, with each equal to zero and a function of $k$ variables, that is, $f_{i}(x_{1},...,x_{k}) = 0$, for $1 \leq i \leq n$. Is there a known algorithm or procedure (which I could program) for reducing the number of equations or number of variables to a minimal amount?

In particular, I want to reduce the runtime of my code by figuring out if I have redundancies in my equations and eliminating those redundancies (such as one equation implying that a variable is equal to zero in all of the others, which would reduce the number of equations and variables).

---

EDIT: I have included a snapshot of my program here:
[image: code]

As you can see from my list of equations, we have that $x_{11}x_{12} + x_{12}x_{22} =0$ implies $x_{11} = - x_{22}$ and thus the entire system reduces to $x_{11}^2 + x_{12}x_{21} =0$. Implementing the Groebner basis command as follows in SAGE did not obtain this result.

```
I = equations*PolynomialRing(CC,len(varlist(n)),varlist(n))
B = I.groebner_basis()
print("The Groebner basis for I is:\n"+str(B))
```

where the list 'equations' is what was printed after "the closure of the nilpotent..." and the varlist(n) is a function I defined which deals with list manipulation and nothing mathematical. I was simply following the sage documentation [here](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/constructions/polynomials.html#grobner-bases). So, what I need is some algorithm which in this example would give me just that my system of polynomial equations equal to zero reduces to $x_{11}^2 + x_{12}x_{21} = 0$.

Comment: I assume this is before you want do do a Gröbner basis computation?
Using Gröbner basis calculations, you can most likely reduce the number of variables in some of the polynomials.

Comment: Compute a Grobner basis? (should be built-in in sage, if not then you can use the command from singular)

Comment: @Per Alexandersson - sorry, we posted comments almost simultaneously, so I didn't see your comment ...

Comment: @Abhinav Kumar: I already tried using the Grobner basis command built into SAGE but it did not compute what I wanted. I will add an edit to my question including this example. I am interested in any alternative techniques to computing a Grobner basis.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that, in this case, changing the term order would do what you want.  But there is no good way of choosing the best term order a priori.

Comment: @Alexander Woo: I'm not sure how term order would affect this and give me a grobner basis of $ x_{11}^2 + x_{12} x_{21}=0 $. Care to expand upon your idea?

Comment: Reading a little more carefully... Actually, what you have written is not right: the equation $x_{11}x_{12} + x_{12}x_{22} = 0$ does NOT imply $x_{11} = -x_{22}$.  Rather, it implies $x_{11} = -x_{22}$ OR $x_{12} = 0$, and you cannot assume the former.  There is something in your problem that is implying that $x_{12}\neq0$, and you can do a colon operation to say you know $x_{12}\neq0$, but obviously you need to know what is implying $x_{12}\neq0$ in order to generalize.